# How can I configure Spring 3 MVC to handle Errors similar to Exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3

There are countless articles explaining basic exception handling using Spring 3 MVC which I have successfully implemented. So now when one of my Controllers throws an Exception class it gets caught properly by my custom exception handler.

However, I cannot get it to throw Error classes to my custom exception handler and this is what I need. Some third party libraries throw Errors which simply bypass my Spring error handling configuration, which seems to be only for Exception and its sub-classes.

Is there any way I can configure it to also include Error types in my custom exception handler?

The following code demonstrates how I set mine up:

```
  <bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.test.ExceptionHandler" p:order="2" >


    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: You are encountering Errors that means you have done something wrong in your code. We are not supposed to catch and handle Errors. If you want to stop the Error stack trace from being displayed on view, just provide a mapping in your deployment descriptor for 500 error code and return an error Page.

Comment: You don't handle errors, you eliminate them. If your app is expecting errors at runtime it's probably not stable to go live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern we have used is to have a `BaseController` that all our Controllers extend using the following format to have specific errors mapped to specific HTTP status and a catch for more the most generic in Exception:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @ExceptionHandler (Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ModelAndView handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        return new JsonError(ex.getMessage()).asModelAndView();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler (InvalidArticleQueryRangeException.class)
    @ResponseStatus (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleAllExceptions(InvalidArticleQueryRangeException ex) {
        return new JsonError(ex.getMessage()).asModelAndView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think this would work? @ExceptionHandler (Error.class)

Comment: @Trant not sure, I'd ask why you would want to do this. Usually Errors are indicative of a catastrophic failure on the VM or in code. Personally I think code outside of your controllers should be throwing Exceptions rather than Errors.

Comment: @Trant that said it should work the API for the annotation is public abstract Class<? extends Throwable>, which Error does.